# How to solve ClassCastException when passing date parameters to jasper report?

Tags: java, date, jasper-reports

I have a report with between date parameters on derby database 
and I have got below message when sending dates through two text fields to run i 
to got below quote error msg.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.setDate(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:615)

My code to call jasper report is here:

```
public void runREport() {
   try {     
       Connection con1= null;

       String Op=jTsubmain_no.getText();
       int val = Integer.parseInt((String) Op.trim());
       Map param1 = new HashMap();
       param1.put("sub_no",val);
       param1.put("fdate",jTfdate.getText());
       param1.put("ldate",jTldate.getText());

       try {
              con1= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527//accountsdb","accounts","accounts");
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(reports.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }

       String jrxmlFileName = "C:/Users/hosam/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Accsys/src/accsys/report2.jrxml";
      JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(jrxmlFileName);
      JasperReport jasperReport =JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
      JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, param1, con1);
      JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint); 
   } catch (JRException ex) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,  ex);
   }    
}
```

Comment: So what is your question? Is it about Jasper, SQL, or date-time handling? Stack Exchange works best for specific narrowly focused question. Please edit away the extraneous details.

Comment: I have got error message for dates intered thourgh my textfileds

Comment: @Basil unable to run report due to parameters for dates is wrong as per err message i stick above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a **different class** between parameter passed and definition in jrxml.

`jTfdate.getText()` is returning an object of type `java.lang.String`

in jrxml you have this definition of parameter

```
<parameter name="fdate" class="java.util.Date">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[""]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

**Solution**, pass a `java.util.Date` object in your parameter map.

Example

```
param1.put("fdate",new SimpleDateFormat("yourPattern").parse(jTfdate.getText()));
```

Where the pattern, `"yourPattern"` should correspond to the text parsed see [SimpleDateFormat pattern's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

How to catch the `ParseException` and set default value, I leave to you.

Comment: i put getdate insteadn gettext rertieving date from date chooser thus the problem solved .